# Perform "outer product" of 2-D matrix and return a 3-D array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, product

I would like to do an operation on a 2-D matrix which somehow looks like the outer product of a vector. I already have written some codes for this task, but it is pretty slow, so I would like to know if there is anything I can do to accelerate it.

I would like to show the code I wrote first, followed by an example to illustrate the task I wanted to do.

---

**My code, version row-by-row**

```
function B = outer2D(A)
    B = zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2),size(A,2)); %Pre-allocate the output array
    for J = 1 : size(A,1)
        B(J,:,:) = transpose(A(J,:))*A(J,:); %Perform outer product on each row of A and assign to the J-th layer of B
    end
end
```

Using the matrix A = randn(30000,20) as the input for testing, it spends 0.317 sec.

---

**My code, version page-by-page**

```
function B = outer2D(A)
    B = zeros(size(A,1),size(A,2),size(A,2)); %Pre-allocate the output array
    for J = 1 : size(A,2)
        B(:,:,J) = repmat(A(:,J),1,size(A,2)).*A; %Evaluate B page-by-page
    end
end
```

Using the matrix A = randn(30000,20) as the input for testing, it spends 0.146 sec.

---

**Example 1**

```
A = [3 0; 1 1; 1 0; -1 1; 0 -2]; %A is the input matrix.
B = outer2D(A);
disp(B)
```

Then I would expect

```
(:,:,1) =

     9     0
     1     1
     1     0
     1    -1
     0     0


(:,:,2) =

     0     0
     1     1
     0     0
    -1     1
     0     4
```

The first row of B, [9 0; 0 0], is the outer product of [3 0],
i.e. [3; 0]*[3 0] = [9 0; 0 0].

The second row of B, [1 1; 1 1], is the outer product of [1 1],
i.e. [1; 1]*[1 1] = [1 1; 1 1].

The third row of B, [1 0; 0 0], is the outer product of [1 0],
i.e. [1; 0]*[1 0] = [1 0; 0 0].

And the same for the remaining rows.

---

**Example 2**

```
A = 
0   -1  -2
0   1   0
-3  0   2
0   0   0
1   0   0

B = outer2D(A)
disp(B)
```

Then, similar to the example 1, the expected output is

```
(:,:,1) =
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
 9     0    -6
 0     0     0
 1     0     0


(:,:,2) =
 0     1     2
 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     0


(:,:,3) =
 0     2     4
 0     0     0
-6     0     4
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
```

---

Because the real input in my project is like in the size of 30000 × 2000 and this task is to be performed for many times. So the acceleration of this task is quite essential for me.

I am thinking of eliminating the for-loop in the function. May I have some opinions on this problem?

Comment: The problem is that the matrix `B` will consume a memory  nearly of size 1 TB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With auto expansion:

```
function B = outer2D(A)
    B=permute(permute(A,[3 1 2]).*A',[2 3 1]);
end
```

Without auto expansion:

```
function B = outer2Dold(A)
    B=permute(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[3 1 2]),A'),[2 3 1]);
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple and effective answer!!

Answer (score -4):

Outer products are not possible in the matlab language.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure if the outer product is impossible in MATLAB. Because, for example, the outer product of A = [1, 2, 3] can be performed by the code transpose(A)*A, and MATLAB does give [1, 2, 3; 2, 4, 6; 3, 6, 9] as the output.
And I just wanted to generalize it from 1-D to 2-D into 2-D to 3-D version.

Comment: Everything is possible in the MATLAB language (and in just most of other languages). That is how programming works